# How to make slow MySQL query run faster

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have this query that often shows me "error code 2013. lost connection to mysql query" whenever I run it:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS elogbook_get_boardid;

CREATE TABLE elogbook_get_boardid AS
  (SELECT DISTINCT `LOTID`,
                   `Board_ID`,
                   `Serial_Number`,
                   coalesce(CASE
                                WHEN A.`Serial_Number` = B.`board_sn` THEN 'In Use'
                                ELSE A.`status`
                            END, '') AS `Status`,
                   coalesce(B.`LOT_LOCATION`, '') AS `chamber`,
                   coalesce(B.`created_date`, '') AS `Start Date`,
                   coalesce(B.`BINOUT_DUE_DATE`, '') AS `Est End`
   FROM hardware_tracking_msa.HAST_Detail A
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT X.*,
             Y.`BINOUT_DUE_DATE`,
             Y.`LOT_LOCATION`
      FROM skynet_msa.lots_to_hast_boards X
      LEFT JOIN skynet_msa.labs_inventory Y ON X.`lotid` = Y.`LOTID`) B ON A.`Serial_Number` = B.`board_sn`
   WHERE `LOTID` IS NOT NULL);
```

I would like to know what makes it take longer than 30 seconds to run and how to improve the query. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Output for hardware_tracking_msa.HAST_Detail:

```
Index, Board_Number, SIG_Number, Board_ID, Serial_Number, Design_ID, Package, Sockets, Socket_Number, Status, Notes, Deleted_By, Inserted_Date, Inserted_By, Updated_Date, Updated_By, Deleted_Date
'1', '2759', '594-11269', '2759-001', '605637/001', 'J4Q2', 'WFBGA, PIN COUNT: 168/529,PACKAGE SIZE: 12x12', '40', '530-10670  SINGLE BIAS (ESPEC)CANNOT USE FOR J80C/J4Q2', '', '', '', '2022-05-17 14:00:00', 'NWANGA', '2022-05-18 10:15:41', 'tmingyao', '2022-05-17 14:57:33'
'2', '2759', '594-11269', '2759-002', '605637/008', 'J4Q2', 'WFBGA, PIN COUNT: 168/529,PACKAGE SIZE: 12x12', '40', '530-10670  SINGLE BIAS (ESPEC)CANNOT USE FOR J80C/J4Q2', NULL, '', '', '2022-05-17 14:00:00', 'NWANGA', '2022-05-17 14:57:33', '', '2022-05-17 14:57:33'
'3', '2759', '594-11269', '2759-003', '608061/001', 'J4Q2', 'WFBGA, PIN COUNT: 168/529,PACKAGE SIZE: 12x12', '40', '530-10670  SINGLE BIAS (ESPEC)CANNOT USE FOR J80C/J4Q2', NULL, '', '', '2022-05-17 14:00:00', 'NWANGA', '2022-05-17 14:57:33', '', '2022-05-17 14:57:33'
```

Output for skynet_msa.lots_to_hast_boards:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
lotid,        & board\_sn,     & created\_date         \\
'CVZ2JL2.11', & '1790247/003', & '2022-07-20 '14:26:04 \\
'CV4YJL2.11', & '1317876/002', & '2022-07-20 14:26:04  \\
'CVRMHL2.11', & '1790241/014', & '2022-07-20 14:26:04 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Output for skynet_msa.labs_inventory:

```
LOTID, LOCATION, ENV_TEST_INTERVAL, EST_DURATION_TIME, ENV_STRESS_VOLTAGE, ENV_STRESS_VOLT_2, ENV_STRESS_VOLT_3, PRODUCT_FAMILY, PRODUCT_TECHNOLOGY, DESIGN_ID, QA_WORK_REQUEST_NO, QA_PROCESS_TYPE, QA_PROCESS_NAME, QA_BURN_EXPERIMENT, QA_CONTACT, QA_PROCESS_LOT_NO, FABRICATION_FACILITY, ASSEMBLY_FACILITY, ELEC_TEST_FLOW, CONFIGURATION_WIDTH, NUMBER_OF_DIE_IN_PKG, CURRENT_QTY, LOT_LOCATION, LEAD_COUNT, PACKAGE_TYPE, PACKAGE_LENGTH, PACKAGE_WIDTH, PACKAGE_HEIGHT, SOAK_LEVEL, BAKE_TEMPERATURE, DRB_TEMPERATURE, ACTUAL_CURE_TIME, REFLOW_PROFILE, PINOUT_VERSION, DISPATCH_DUE_DATE, BINOUT_DUE_DATE, ROW_CREATED, ROW_MODIFIED, LOCATION_DATE, LOCATION_WW, MODULE_LOT, BURN_LOT, MONITOR_IGNORE, TICKER, PRIORITY, ASM_LOT_NUMBER, MARK_FORMAT, LOCATION_TAT, RPM_WW, QA_EVENT_ID, TC_WEIGHT, AUTOMOTIVE_LOT, CUSTOMER_OPTION, PKG_RECEIVE_DATE, CUSTOMER_GROUP, SAMPLE_PULLED_DATE, QA_SPECIAL_FLOW, QA_BLOCKS, PROBE_CUSTOM_TESTED, QA_PROGRAM_REV, NAND_FLOW_TYPE, NUM_FLASH_CE_PINS, RETICLE_WAVE_ID, MAJOR_PROBE_PROG_REV, MAJOR_TEST_PROG_REV, CYCLING_TYPE, QA_TARGET_CYCLE, LAST_TEST_INTERVAL, CYCLING_TEMPERATURE, ENV_STRESS_DURATION, FIRST_TEST_INTERVAL, DRB_TARGET_INTERVAL, LTDR_TEMPERATURE, RD_STRESS_TYPE
'1623941.001', 'TEMP CYCLE K INV', '25', '12.50', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', 'MCP', 'ALL IN ONE MCP', 'UM181', '', 'PRODUCTION SCREEN', 'TEMP CYCLE K', '', '', '', 'MIXED', 'ASSEMBLY-MSA', '', '', '8', '2439', 'S01-AR-ASRSIN', '254/432', 'TFBGA', '13.000', '11.500', '1.100', '', '0', '0', '0', '', 'JEDEC', '1970-01-01 00:00:00', NULL, '2022-06-05 18:35:12', '2022-06-06 00:00:16', '2022-06-05 18:35:00', '202223', '0', '0', '0', '0', '4', '1623941.001', '', '1.57', '', 'QA 13', '0', '', '', '1970-01-01 00:00:00', '', '1970-01-01 00:00:00', '', '', 'MOBILE C', '', '', '4', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '25', '', '', '', ''
'BC4WSXZ.31', 'THERMAL WARPAGE', '0', '0.00', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', 'MCP', 'MASSFLASH/LPDDR4', 'J86L', '', 'PRODUCTION SCREEN', 'THERMAL WARPAGE', '', '', '', 'MIXED', 'PTI P3', '', '', '2', '26', '', '194/1026', 'UFBGA', '9.000', '12.500', '0.545', '', '0', '0', '0', '', 'AVALON', '1970-01-01 00:00:00', NULL, '2022-07-19 11:00:17', '2022-07-20 13:30:15', '2022-07-19 11:26:45', '202229', '0', '0', '0', '0', '4', 'PT22900.25', 'AVALON', '0.28', '', 'QA 32', '0', '', '', '1970-01-01 00:00:00', '', '2022-07-19 10:58:00', '', '', '', '', '', '1', '', '', '29', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''
'BC6VVLZ.31', 'TEMP CYCLE K INV', '25', '12.50', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', 'MCP', 'MASSFLASH/CONTROLLER', 'J39E', '', 'PRODUCTION SCREEN', 'TEMP CYCLE K', '', '', '', 'FAB 10', 'ASSEMBLY-MSA', '', 'X4-X8', '4', '320', 'S01-REL-LAB-IN', '153/196', 'VFBGA', '13.000', '11.500', '1.000', '', '0', '0', '0', '', 'JEDEC', '1970-01-01 00:00:00', NULL, '2022-07-10 14:35:16', '2022-07-11 07:15:19', '2022-07-10 14:31:49', '202228', '0', '0', '0', '0', '4', 'BF3HFCQ.5X', '', '419.25', '', 'QA 45', '0', 'YES', 'AUTOMOTIVE', '1970-01-01 00:00:00', '', '1970-01-01 00:00:00', '', '', 'NAND AUTO', '', '', '4', 'WAVE007', '22', '', '', '', '', '', '25', '', '', '', ''
```

show create table hardware_tracking_msa.HAST_Detail:

```
CREATE TABLE `HAST_Detail` (
    `Index` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `Board_Number` varchar(250) DEFAULT \'\', 
    `SIG_Number` varchar(250) DEFAULT \'\', 
    `Board_ID` varchar(250) DEFAULT \'\', 
    `Serial_Number` varchar(250) DEFAULT \'\', 
    `Design_ID` varchar(150) DEFAULT \'\', 
    `Package` varchar(250) DEFAULT \'\', 
    `Sockets` int DEFAULT \'0\', 
    `Socket_Number` varchar(250) DEFAULT \'\', 
    `Status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `Notes` varchar(1000) DEFAULT \'\', 
    `Deleted_By` varchar(20) DEFAULT \'\', 
    `Inserted_Date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    `Inserted_By` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\', 
    `Updated_Date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    `Updated_By` varchar(20) DEFAULT \'\', 
    `Deleted_Date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`Index`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1459 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

show create table skynet_msa.lots_to_hast_boards:

```
CREATE TABLE `lots_to_hast_boards` (
    `lotid` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\', 
    `board_sn` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\', 
    `created_date` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`lotid`,`board_sn`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

show create table skynet_msa.labs_inventory:

```
CREATE TABLE `labs_inventory` (
    `LOTID` varchar(12) NOT NULL, 
    `LOCATION` varchar(48) NOT NULL, 
    `ENV_TEST_INTERVAL` int DEFAULT \'0\', 
    `EST_DURATION_TIME` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT \'0.00\', 
    `ENV_STRESS_VOLTAGE` decimal(6,3) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `ENV_STRESS_VOLT_2` decimal(6,3) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `ENV_STRESS_VOLT_3` decimal(6,3) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `PRODUCT_FAMILY` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `PRODUCT_TECHNOLOGY` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `DESIGN_ID` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `QA_WORK_REQUEST_NO` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `QA_PROCESS_TYPE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `QA_PROCESS_NAME` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `QA_BURN_EXPERIMENT` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `QA_CONTACT` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `QA_PROCESS_LOT_NO` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `FABRICATION_FACILITY` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `ASSEMBLY_FACILITY` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `ELEC_TEST_FLOW` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `CONFIGURATION_WIDTH` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `NUMBER_OF_DIE_IN_PKG` int DEFAULT NULL, 
    `CURRENT_QTY` int DEFAULT NULL, 
    `LOT_LOCATION` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `LEAD_COUNT` varchar(45) DEFAULT \'\', 
    `PACKAGE_TYPE` varchar(45) DEFAULT \'\', 
    `PACKAGE_LENGTH` decimal(6,3) DEFAULT \'0.000\', 
    `PACKAGE_WIDTH` decimal(6,3) DEFAULT \'0.000\', 
    `PACKAGE_HEIGHT` decimal(6,3) DEFAULT \'0.000\', 
    `SOAK_LEVEL` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `BAKE_TEMPERATURE` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `DRB_TEMPERATURE` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `ACTUAL_CURE_TIME` int DEFAULT NULL, 
    `REFLOW_PROFILE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `PINOUT_VERSION` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `DISPATCH_DUE_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
    `BINOUT_DUE_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
    `ROW_CREATED` datetime NOT NULL, 
    `ROW_MODIFIED` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    `LOCATION_DATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT \'1970-01-01 12:00:00\', 
    `LOCATION_WW` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `MODULE_LOT` int NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\', 
    `BURN_LOT` int DEFAULT \'0\', 
    `MONITOR_IGNORE` int NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\', 
    `TICKER` int NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\', 
    `PRIORITY` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `ASM_LOT_NUMBER` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `MARK_FORMAT` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `LOCATION_TAT` double DEFAULT \'0\', 
    `RPM_WW` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `QA_EVENT_ID` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `TC_WEIGHT` double DEFAULT \'0\', 
    `AUTOMOTIVE_LOT` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `CUSTOMER_OPTION` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `PKG_RECEIVE_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
    `CUSTOMER_GROUP` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `SAMPLE_PULLED_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
    `QA_SPECIAL_FLOW` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `QA_BLOCKS` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `PROBE_CUSTOM_TESTED` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `QA_PROGRAM_REV` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `NAND_FLOW_TYPE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `NUM_FLASH_CE_PINS` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `RETICLE_WAVE_ID` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `MAJOR_PROBE_PROG_REV` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `MAJOR_TEST_PROG_REV` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `CYCLING_TYPE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `QA_TARGET_CYCLE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `LAST_TEST_INTERVAL` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `CYCLING_TEMPERATURE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `ENV_STRESS_DURATION` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `FIRST_TEST_INTERVAL` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `DRB_TARGET_INTERVAL` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `LTDR_TEMPERATURE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `RD_STRESS_TYPE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`LOTID`), 
    KEY `design_id` (`DESIGN_ID`), 
    KEY `lot_location` (`LOT_LOCATION`), 
    KEY `burn` (`DESIGN_ID`,`QA_BURN_EXPERIMENT`), 
    KEY `locations` (`LOT_LOCATION`,`LOCATION`), 
    KEY `all_index` (`LOCATION`,`LOT_LOCATION`,`DISPATCH_DUE_DATE`,`PRODUCT_FAMILY`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
       COMMENT=\'table to store MAM data for msa labs skynet\''
```

EXPLAIN QUERY:

```
id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'X', NULL, 'ALL', 'PRIMARY', NULL, NULL, NULL, '55', '90.00', 'Using where'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'Y', NULL, 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '14', 'skynet_msa.X.lotid', '1', '100.00', 'Using where'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'A', NULL, 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '1458', '10.00', 'Using where; Using join buffer (hash join)'
```

Comment: Better. Edit question to include `show create table hardware_tracking_msa.HAST_Detail` output, `show create table skynet_msa.lots_to_hast_boards` output, an `explain SELECT DISTINCT ...{rest of query}`.

Comment: And `show create table skynet_msa.labs_inventory` for good measure. How much of the `elogbook_get_boardid` table is changed during the regeneration? Are queries that INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE based on the other 3 tables acceptable?

Comment: Done. the elogbook_get_boardid is to get the most recent data at that timing (machines in use at that time)

Comment: i am supp to create a new table i cannot change the previous 3 tables

Comment: `show create table hardware_tracking_msa.HAST_Detail` was a SQL statement that would show all the data types of the table and the indexes of the original table. `EXPLAIN {query}` is also a SQL statement returning how the query was executed and therefore what decisions it made to make it longer than 30 seconds. Those outputs would still be appreciated. Can you add indexes to the original table?
The "INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE" comment was about using the original tables as read only, but using a comparison of their content to update your table.

Comment: i updated the show create event statements. im not sure i can change the 3 tables

Answer (score 0):

Change from MyISAM to InnoDB.  (It may not matter for *this* query.)

Tentative index to add:

```
A:  INDEX(Serial_Number,  status)
```

LEFT is not needed:

```
LEFT JOIN ( ... ) B  ON ...  WHERE b.id IS NOT NULL
```

-->

```
JOIN ( ... ) B  ON ...
```

At that point, it *may* be reasonable to get rid of the nested LEFT JOIN, and simply have a single level A, X, Y joined together.

The EXPLAIN shows that at least some of those simplifications were automatically figured out by the Optimizer.

A.`Serial_Number` = B.`board_sn

I see "utf8" and "latin1".  If any query JOINs on a VARCHAR between different Character Sets, (ore Collations), an otherwise-suitable index will not be used.  If that is a problem, I suggest you use `ALTER .. CONVERT TO ..` to change latin1 to utf8.

I see columns called "DURATION" and "INTERVAL" being declared `VARCHAR`.  This can cause trouble if you ever do numeric operations on such columns.  (I understand things like "BOARD_SN" are not really numbers.)

Comment: table A alr has index in it

Comment: Sorry, all I saw was the PRIMARY KEY.  Is it a composite index withexactly thow two columns in that order?

Comment: table A does not have composite index only one index. Table X has composite index, 2 indexes while table Y has many indexes

Comment: And I am recommending adding a particular composite index to table A.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: and wht kind of column i shld add to A?

Comment: nvm managed to do it @RickJames

Comment: but it still runs slow that it keeps losing connection

Comment: it still runs v slow and keeps losing connection. do u have any alternative suggestion? i tried ur suggestions