# How to make an insert function mysql query run faster?

Tags: mysql

I have this query that sometimes takes more than 30 seconds to run and results in "error code 2013. lost connection to mysql query" (EDITED):

```
INSERT INTO elogbook_get_boardid
SELECT DISTINCT
Y.`LOTID`, 
`Board_ID`, 
`Serial_Number`, 
coalesce(CASE WHEN A.`Serial_Number` = X.`board_sn` THEN 'In Use' ELSE 
A.`status` END, '') AS `Status`,
coalesce(Y.`LOT_LOCATION`,'') AS `chamber`, 
coalesce(X.`created_date`, '') AS `Start Date`, 
coalesce(Y.`BINOUT_DUE_DATE`, '') AS `Est End`, 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS `Current Time` 
FROM hardware_tracking_msa.HAST_Detail A 
JOIN skynet_msa.lots_to_hast_boards X 
LEFT JOIN skynet_msa.labs_inventory Y 
ON X.`lotid` = Y.`LOTID` 
ON A.`Serial_Number` = X.`board_sn`;
```

I want to know how to make it run faster. It usually only inserts around 60 rows every time it is run

Edited:

table description:

```
'elogbook_get_boardid', 
'CREATE TABLE `elogbook_get_boardid` (
\n  `LOTID` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `Board_ID` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `Serial_Number` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `Status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `chamber` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `Start Date` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `Est End` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `Current Time` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

Explain function:

```
Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
'LOTID', 'varchar(45)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'Board_ID', 'varchar(45)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'Serial_Number', 'varchar(45)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'Status', 'varchar(45)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'chamber', 'varchar(45)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'Start Date', 'varchar(45)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'Est End', 'varchar(45)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'Current Time', 'varchar(45)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
```

EXPLAIN SELECT function in the original query (EDITED):

```
id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'X', NULL, 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '80', '100.00', 'Using temporary'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'Y', NULL, 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '50', 'skynet_msa.X.lotid', '1', '100.00', 'Using where'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'A', NULL, 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '1456', '100.00', 'Using where; Using join buffer (hash join)'
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
'-> Table scan on <temporary>  (actual time=0.001..0.007 rows=80 loops=1)\n
-> Temporary table with deduplication  (cost=11716.50 rows=116480) (actual time=2.047..2.056 rows=80 loops=1)\n        
-> Filter: (convert(hardware_tracking_msa.A.Serial_Number using utf8mb4) = X.board_sn)  (cost=11716.50 rows=116480) (actual time=1.207..1.825 rows=82 loops=1)\n            
-> Inner hash join (<hash>(convert(hardware_tracking_msa.A.Serial_Number using utf8mb4))=<hash>(X.board_sn))  (cost=11716.50 rows=116480) (actual time=1.206..1.807 rows=82 loops=1)\n                
-> Table scan on A  (cost=1.91 rows=1456) (actual time=0.031..0.458 rows=1456 loops=1)\n                
-> Hash\n                    
-> Nested loop left join  (cost=61.67 rows=80) (actual time=0.069..1.042 rows=80 loops=1)\n                        
-> Table scan on X  (cost=8.67 rows=80) (actual time=0.021..0.490 rows=80 loops=1)\n                        
-> Filter: (X.lotid = Y.LOTID)  (cost=0.56 rows=1) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=80)\n                            
-> Single-row index lookup on Y using PRIMARY (LOTID=X.lotid)  (cost=0.56 rows=1) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=80)\n'
```

Comment: Please add table definitions as text so we can see the indexes and the result of an EXPLAIN. Also does the running the select only return expected results in an acceptable time?

Comment: Need to see all the tables invoked in the select - add result of show create table tablename for all tables.

Comment: @P.Salmon can refer to this qn i asked previously https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73046761/how-to-make-slow-mysql-query-run-faster/73055521?noredirect=1#comment129037717_73055521

Comment: Get rid of the subquery. Create suitable indices. Find why DISTINCT needed, and try to get rid of it.

Comment: A) Check your server tuning. Give InnoDB more memory! B) If you're doing a lot of inserts and you can lock the table, lock, disable indexes, insert, re-enable indexes and unlock. C) Consider `LOAD DATA INFILE` for huge loads.

Comment: Using `45` all over the place is asking for silent truncation issues. Why not `255`?

Comment: @Akina distinct is needed bc there are repeating of LOTID tht i need to get rid of

Comment: @Akina u meant create index? does tht not make it run slower?

Comment: Indexes make SELECTs run a lot faster, while making INSERTs run a tiny bit slower.  Sounds like a good tradeoff to me!

Answer (score 0):

What indexes do you have?

Try to avoid `JOIN ( SELECT ... )`; instead try to join directly to the two tables in that subquery.

The WHERE clause is implying that X.LOTID might be NULL; it it so declared?  (You are missing two `CREATE TABLEs`.  Meanwhile you listed a table that does not seem to be used!)

These indexes *may* help:

```
A:  INDEX(Serial_Number,  status)
Y:  INDEX(LOTID,  BINOUT_DUE_DATE, LOT_LOCATION)
X:  INDEX(lotid)
```

If `lots_to_hast_boards` is a many-to-many mapping table, see this for advice on indexing:  [*Many-to-many*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Spell out the columns needed instead of `X.*`.

After those are fixed, we may find a way to get rid of `DISTINCT` (which takes an extra pass over the data and a sort).

The `EXPLAIN` we need is `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Splitting a date time into two columns is *usually* a bad idea.  What queries do you have that involve those columns?

Putting dates/times into VARCHAR makes it essentially impossible to compare or order them.

While I am on this kind of rant, are your ids and numbers really numeric?  If so, use a suitable numeric datatype.

**Character set / Collation**

Notice the `CONVERT(...)`. It imples that A.`Serial_Number` and B.`board_sn` are no the same character set and collation.  This *may* be the cause of the slowdown.  A "serial number" sounds like an ascii string; consider making them both ascii.

Comment: i alr removed the join (select) but i cannot add more indexes and i think for now there is no way to remove distinct bc there are repeat data in lotid

Comment: i updated the explain select of the original query

Comment: only lot_to_hast_boards has index the rest only have primary keys

Comment: IDs and numbers have '-' and '/' so they r not entirely numbers

Comment: table A has index already and primary key for serial_number

Comment: GQS - "cannot add more indexes" -- why not?  My composite index would be better than your single-column index.

Comment: i managed to add all indices u suggested and checked using explain analyze but sometimes it still runs more than 30 seconds. Do u have any idea how to approach this differently?

Comment: @GQS - charset inconsistency?

Comment: How to convert the board_sn to an ascii string?

Comment: serial_number has format as such:  605637/001. Is it considered ascii string?

Comment: i think the convert part is just bc they want to change to utf8mb4?